# Call XML array from public method AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, class, load, external

I want to get the xml data and put it into an array of objects. I use this public method:

```
package 
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class parseXML_public 
{
    static private var myXML:XML;
    static private var xml_array:Array=new Array;

    public function parseXML_public() {

        }

        public static function  crearXMLArray(s:String):Array{

        loadXML(s);
        return xml_array;
        }

        static private function loadXML(s:String):void 
        {
            var myURLRequest:URLRequest;
            var myURLLoader: URLLoader;
            myURLRequest = new URLRequest();
            myURLRequest.url = s;
            myURLLoader = new URLLoader();
            myURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLComplete);
            myURLLoader.load(myURLRequest);

        }

        static private function onXMLComplete(e:Event):void 
        {
            myXML = new XML(e.target.data);     
            parseXML();
        }

        static private function parseXML():void 
        {
            var i:Number;
            var j:Number;
            var nodos:Number;
            var my_obj:Object;
            nodos = Math.floor(myXML.*.*.length() / (myXML.*.length()));
            for (i = 0; i < myXML.*.length(); i++) {

                xml_array[i] = new Array();

                for (j = 0; j < nodos; j++) {

                    my_obj = new Object();
                    my_obj.nombre = myXML.child(i).child(j).@nombre;
                    my_obj.posX = myXML.child(i).child(j).@posX;
                    my_obj.posY = myXML.child(i).child(j).@posY;
                    xml_array[i].push(my_obj);
                }   
            }

       //trace(xml_array); //--> It shows the array charged!
        }

}
```

}

And when i call the array from the main class i do:

```
parseXML_public.crearXMLArray("xml/xml_tonalidades.xml"));
```

(if i trace this, the array is empty) I think it has to do with the URLLoader and waiting it before doing the return, but can't figure how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the array is tracing empty is because you need to wait for it to load. Here is what I would do.

In your main class add an event listener to wait for the data to return.

```
parseXML_public.addEventListener("xmlLoadComplete", doSomething);
parseXML_public.crearXMLArray("xml/xml_tonalidades.xml")); 

function doSomething(e:Event){
    // Array is ready now
}
```

And in your loader class add this when you want the event to be fired.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event("xmlLoadComplete",true,false));
```

Maybe something like this.

```
static private function parseXML():void 
{
    var i:Number;
    var j:Number;
    var nodos:Number;
    var my_obj:Object;
    nodos = Math.floor(myXML.*.*.length() / (myXML.*.length()));
    for (i = 0; i < myXML.*.length(); i++) {
       xml_array[i] = new Array();
       for (j = 0; j < nodos; j++) {
           my_obj = new Object();
           my_obj.nombre = myXML.child(i).child(j).@nombre;
           my_obj.posX = myXML.child(i).child(j).@posX;
           my_obj.posY = myXML.child(i).child(j).@posY;
           xml_array[i].push(my_obj);
       }   
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("xmlLoadComplete",true,false));
}
```

Keep in mind you might have to import some event classes for this to compile. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! I had to instance the class because trying to get the dispatchEvent from a static private function did't work!

I added in parseXML_public the 


dispatchEvent(new Event("xmlLoadComplete", true, false));


as you said, and from my main class i did the following: 


var myExternalXML:parseXML_public = new parseXML_public();
   myExternalXML.crearXMLArray("xml/xml_tonalidades.xml");
   myExternalXML.addEventListener("xmlLoadComplete", doSomething);


and in doSomething i copied the array!

Thank you very much!

Comment: AlmosT forget! I also changed the static private vars into public and not static!